# Connectionstring dynamic SqlExpress 2008

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-express

I´ve got the following connectionstring:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Harald\\Desktop\\Farmer´s Calc\\Programmierung\\WPF\\Finanz_WPF\\Finanz_WPF\\Datenbank\\FarmersCalc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

I need to make it dynamic, not the whole path should be included...
I tried it with `|DataDirectory|` but it seems to work just in ASP.NET.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).